# How to deploy plutus/marlowe contract on Cardano blockchain

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, cardano-node, marlowe

i am developing smart contract in plutus/marlowe playground which i compiled and simulate contracts successfully but now i want to deploy a contract on Cardano blockchain

Comment: You'll need a way to submit the transaction. Most devs have only had a few weeks to see the final version so tools might still be a while away. Are you technically skilled enough to install cardano node on your own?

Comment: @PatrickSturm yes I already installed Cardano node and CLI both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialise your on-chain validator into Plutus Script. You can use some of the existing examples here https://github.com/james-iohk/Alonzo-testnet/tree/update-cabal-1.29.0/resources/plutus-sources to see how your on-chain codes can be serialised and exported into *.plutus format. Then you can use Cardano cli to construct transaction and play with your smart contract, which is essentially a hash of Plutus Script. This link https://plutus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plutus/howtos/exporting-a-script.html is also useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have the technical know-how so I will just post the link in question. So keep in mind, give it a good read. Marlowe JS compiles to Haskell Plutus which is further compiled to Plutus Bytecode/Opcode, can't recall which, not sure it matters. But at the transaction level, we will always be sending the most raw format, bytecode/opcodes.

See [Plutus Enabled Transactions](https://docs.cardano.org/plutus/Plutus-transactions)